# Java - error when submitting app to Mac Store (deprecated API usage)

Tags: java, macos, app-store

I tried to submit Java app to mac store (of course JRE is bundled), but got famous "Invalid Binary Error". In the email from iTunes I got message that "Apple no longer accepts submissions of apps that use Quick Time APIs". That probably means that the bundled JRE points to QTKit Framework or QuickTime Framework. I checked and this API is no longer supported in MAC OS X 10.9.

I use Java 1.7.40.

Do have somebody idea where do Java reference these frameworks and if it is possible to remove those binaries ? I think this is quite fresh problem and I hope there is solution for that.

Thanks, 
Lubos

Comment: As far I as know, this would be coming through via the custom libraries provided by Apple. It might be worthwhile asking Apple if they have any ideas about where this might be and/or if they know of a solution...

Comment: I resolved that faster as I expected actually. By running Unix command "otool -L" it is possible to find all the references to GTKitFramework. In the case of JRE 1.7.40 there are 2 .dylib files by removing of which it was accepted.

Comment: You might want to put that down as answer, we details about how you removed the references etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I resolved the issue faster as I expected. Here are some details.

Run Unix command **otool -L** over directory of bundled JRE to find all *dylib files. This will list all the references of all the dylib files. Then you just need to search in the results the string 
"QTKit". 
In the case of java 1.7.40, there are 2 libraries, referencing that Framework:

**libgstplugins-lite.dylib, 
libjfxmedia.dylib**

If your application doesn't use them, you're lucky and just remove them.

Unix command Example:

**otool -L /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/*dylib**

Hopefully this will help guys, who want to submit Java app to Mac store after GTKit.framework was deprecated in OS X 10.9.

**Note:** this is valid for Java 1.7.40, it might be that for new java versions, this is already fixed.

Regards,

Lubos