# Get "a sealed resource is missing or invalid" error after sign mac app

Tags: macos, libgdx, sign, codesign

after I sign my app using libgdx, I received an email from apple with content:

> Invalid Signature - the nested app bundle Java SE 7 at path MyApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk is signed but the signature is invalid. The following error(s) were reported from codesign:a sealed resource is missing or invalid

This is my sign script:

> distdir=$(dirname $(dirname "$0"))/dist
>
> codesign --deep -v -f -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: MY TEAM" --entitlements "$(dirname $(dirname "$0"))/mac/Entitlements.plist" "$distdir/MYAPP.app"
>
> find $distdir/MYAPP.app/Contents/ -type f ( -name "*.jnilib" -or -name "*.jar" -or -name "*.dylib" ) -exec codesign --verbose -f -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: MY TEAM" --entitlements "$(dirname $(dirname "$0"))/mac/Entitlements.plist" {} \;
>
> find $distdir/MYAPP.app/Contents/ -type f ( -name "*.jnilib" -or -name "*.jar" -or -name "*.dylib" ) -exec codesign --verbose --verify {} \;
>   find $distdir/MYAPP.app/Contents/ -type f -name "libgstplugins-lite.dylib" -exec rm -f {} \;
>
> find $distdir/MYAPP.app/Contents/ -type f -name "libjfxmedia.dylib" -exec rm -f {} \;

What wrong with my sign code? 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `codesign --display --verbose=4 YourApp.app`?

Comment: Why do you sign the `dylibs` then remove them? o_O — It's a pretty sure bet that's why they are missing.

Comment: Follow this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008617/java-error-when-submitting-app-to-mac-store-deprecated-api-usage),  I have to remove libjfxmedia.dylib to avoid reject when upload my app to mac store.